# 500 Internal server error using codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, captcha

I am using codeigniter for my site. Now I am working to get captcha. For refreshing captcha image, I use Jquery Ajax. When Jquery is calling my captcha_refresh function in controller, I get Internal server error.
Here is my controller:

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    //start session
    session_start();
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $this->load->helper('captcha');

}

function index() { ...}

 //here goes some code

 // For new image on click refresh button.
 function captcha_refresh(){
     header('Content-type: application/json');
    $values = array(
        'word' => '',
        'word_length' => 8,
        'img_path' => './images/images/',
        'img_url' => base_url() .'images/images/',
        'font_path' => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
        'img_width' => '150',
        'img_height' => 50,
        'expiration' => 3600
    );
    $data= create_captcha($values);
    $_SESSION['captchaWord'] = $data['word'];
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;

}

}
```

And here is my js function:

```
function refresh_captcha() {
  new Ajax.Request(baseURL + 'Register/captcha_refresh', {
    method: 'get',
    evalJSON: true,
    parameters: {},
    onSuccess: function (transport) {
        var answer = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
    },
    onError: function () {
        alert('Error');
    },
    onComplete: function () {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So the server has told the browser that "Something has gone wrong!" and probably included a human friendly message to the effect that the sysad should look in the server error logs to find out what went wrong. **Look in the server error logs to find out what went wrong.**

Comment: where can I find server error logs? I am using wamp

Comment: Do you use the 'routes' file at config folder?